# Zend + Doctrine. Сортировка таблицы

Tags: php, сортировка, doctrine2, zend-framework-2

Прошу не судить строго, я новичок, с Zend знаком слабо. Помогите разобраться как создать сортировку для таблицы в ZendFramework2 используя Doctrine.
Нашел tutorial - http://bigemployee.com/zend-framework-2-pagination-sorting-tutorial/ который не могу применить к доктрине.
Согласно инструкции следующий код нужно вставить в объект таблицы :

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
...
public function fetchAll(Select $select = null) {
    if (null === $select)
        $select = new Select();
    $select->from($this->table);
    $resultSet = $this->selectWith($select);
    $resultSet->buffer();
    return $resultSet;
}
...
```

Но в сущности Doctrine нет свойства $this->table.

И в контроллере нужно указать метод fetchAll(), которого так же нет в сущности:

```
return new ViewModel(array(
                'albums' => $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll($select),
                'order_by' => $order_by,
                'order' => $order,
            ));
```

Пример моей сущности которую нужно сортировать по всем столбцам таблицы, кроме id:

```
namespace Admin\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Customer
{
private $id;
private $login;
private $password;
private $email;
private $category;

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
public function setLogin($login)
{
    $this->login = $login;

    return $this;
}
public function getLogin()
{
    return $this->login;
}
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}
public function setCategory(\Admin\Entity\Category $category = null)
{
    $this->category = $category;

    return $this;
}
public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->category;
}
}
```

Мой IndexAction в контроллере выглядит следующим образом:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $query
        ->select('u')
        ->from('Admin\Entity\Customer', 'u')
        ->orderBy('u.id', 'DESC');

    $adapter = new DoctrineAdapter(new ORMPaginator($query));

    $paginator = new Paginator($adapter);
    $paginator->setDefaultItemCountPerPage(3);
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber((int) $this->params()->fromQuery('page', 1));

    return array('customers' => $paginator);
```

Как сортировать таблицу сущности доктрины в таком случае? У доктрины методов для сортировки таблицы не нашел.

Comment: А чем `->orderBy('u.id', 'DESC');` не сортитовка?`

Comment: необходимо сделать сортировку по нажатию на столбец ASC\DESC как по ссылке в начале

Comment: По меняйте desс на asc. И столбец если надо. Вам надо сортировать запросом а не PHP.

Comment: Вы или не дочитал пример или не поняли его. Та делают именно так как я сказал.

Comment: Вот я и не могу применить запрос из этого руководства к моей таблице так как в руководстве подключение по средствам Zend, а у меня сущность доктрины.

Comment: Что вам мешает поменять ваш код на ->orderBy($order_by, $order);

Comment: Думал нужно лезть в методы доктрины и придумывать велосипед, а все оказалось на поверхности! Вот до этого я и не додумался) Премного благодарен, работает!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном контроллере сущности можно сортировать в самом запросе.

Меняем

```
    ->orderBy('u.id', 'DESC');
```

на

```
    ->orderBy('u.'.$order_by, $order);
```

А все остальное будет как в туториале.

Comment: `->orderBy('u.'.$order_by, $order);`